# Error: Sub or funtion not defined - Simple subtotal macro

Tags: vba, subtotal

I have this simple code:

```
Range("A1:C201").Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

When I try to run the macro it shows the error "Sub or funtion not defined". I do not see any sintax error, so I am not sure if it is an issue with my VB set up?

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you sure the message comes from these 2 lines?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this error, but you should consider using the constant `xlSummaryBelow` instead of  `True` in the statement `SummaryBelowData:=`.

Comment: You will need to post the whole function and not just these 2 lines. There is nothing wrong with these lines.

Answer (score 1):

All code must exist within a sub or function. You can't write code outside of these constructs.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub runSubTotal()
    Range("A1:C201").Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=xlSummaryBelow
End Sub
```

NOTE: Instead of making the scope of this subroutine static, you could make it work with any selected range. With the following code you would select your data in the sheet and then run the macro. It would accept anything selected by the user:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub runSubTotal()
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: But that would throw an error msg "*invalid outside procedure*"

Comment: Except I've ran this code in a test sheet and it works with no such error. What procedure do you think this code is outside of?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code of the OP - if you put this outside of any sub, this is what the VBA compiler throws.

Comment: Aha. So we need to see the full code and not just 2 lines.

Comment: Yeah, and I still assume that the error message comes from something else.

Comment: I just tried, and I am getting the same error: Compile error Sub or function not defined. And it highlights the array segment into the code   Option Explicit

Array(2),

Comment: This line works. Your problem is elsewhere. We need to see the full code.